# Ionic Angular Registration with Django backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a user registration with Angular, that creates a user in my Django backend. When I press the Signup button nothing happens.

This is my first time working with Angular, so I understand my syntax and logic might be completely off. But I feel like if I can learn this part, It will set me up for doing the other things I need to do with Angular.

To save myself some time I'm trying to appropriate [Tivix's angular-django-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/angular-django-registration-auth) from github into my own project, so my controller really is just the Tivix one, that I tried to shove into my own project, but I can't seem to make it work. I'm sorry if this question is stupid, but I'm still trying to learn Angular, and how all the pieces are supposed to work together.

Note: my API Server is running on localhost:8000 and Ionic is running on localhost:4400, so I don't know if that might be a problem too?

Here's my controller:

```js
.controller('signupCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', // The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams, djangoAuth, Validate) {
    $scope.model = { 'username': '', 'password': '', 'email': '' };
    $scope.complete = false;
    $scope.register = function (formData) {
        $scope.errors = [];
        Validate.form_validation(formData, $scope.errors);
        if (!formData.$invalid) {
            djangoAuth.register($scope.model.username, $scope.model.password1, $scope.model.password2, $scope.model.email)
            .then(function (data) {
                // success case
                $scope.complete = true;
            }, function (data) {
                // error case
                $scope.errors = data;
            });
        }
    }

}])
```

```html
<ion-view title="Signup" hide-nav-bar="true" id="page2" style="background-color:#F1F1F1;">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="manual-ios-statusbar-padding">
        <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 18px;"></div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/aSVlyHt1SqywcHmw4wIg_logo.svg" width="80%" height="auto" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        </div>
        <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 59px;"></div>
        <div ng-controller="signupCtrl">
        <form id="signup-form1" ng-if="authenticated != true" ng-submit="register(registerForm)" novalidate class="list">
            <ion-list id="signup-list1">
                <label class="item item-input" id="signup-input1">
                    <span class="input-label">Email:</span>
                    <input type="email" ng-model="model.email" placeholder="">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input" id="signup-input2">
                    <span class="input-label">Username:</span>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="model.username" placeholder="">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input" id="signup-input3">
                    <span class="input-label">Password:</span>
                    <input type="password" ng-model="model.password1" placeholder="">
                </label>
            </ion-list>
            <button id="signup-button12" style="left:-10px;" type="submit" class="button button-energized  button-full">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
        </div>
       <!-- <div style="margin-right:-20px;">
            <button id="signup-button12" style="left:-10px;" type="submit" class="button button-energized  button-full">Sign Up</button>
        </div>-->
        <a ui-sref="login" id="signup-button6" class="button button-positive  button-block button-clear">Or login</a>
    </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```